# Can you reference a value from a POM file in Mule workflow?

Tags: mule, pom.xml, dereference, anypoint-studio

Can you reference a value from a POM file in Mule?

I am using Anypoint Studio 6.2 and Mule 3.8.3 and want to reference a value in my workflow but ${total_timeout} does not work so is there other syntax that I should use?

Thanks

Comment: can you explain the scenario bit more clearly. Why you trying to refer value from pom to mule workflow?.

Comment: Its actually in existing code but it is throwing an error when running locally but works when I move it into a properties file.  The value is taken from the mule-maven-plugin configuration in the POM and contains timeout values which are being referenced as ${msg_total_timeout} etc.  The error I see in Anypoint console is that the ${msg_total_timeout} cannot be resolved.  Just wanted to see if referencing it from a POM is possible and they have just coded this wrong but haven't found anything useful in my searches so far